# How to query multi-valued array fields in Elasticsearch using Java client?

Tags: java, rest, elasticsearch, lucene

Using the Elasticsearch High Level REST Client for Java v7.3

I have a few fields in the schema that look like this:

```
{
   "document_type" : ["Utility", "Credit"]
}
```

Basically one field could have an array of strings as the value. I not only need to query for a specific document_type, but also a general string query.

I've tried the following code:

```
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(terms))
                .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("document_type", "Utility"));
```

...which does not return any results. If I remove the ".filter()" part the query returns fine, but the filter appears to prevent any results from coming back. I'm suspecting it's because document_type is a multi-valued array - maybe I'm wrong though. How would I build a query query all documents for specific terms, but also filter by document_type?

Answer (score 0):

I think, the reason is the wrong query. Consider using the [term**s**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) query instead of term query. There is also a eqivalent in the [java api](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.5.1/org/elasticsearch/index/query/QueryBuilders.html#termsQuery-java.lang.String-java.util.Collection-).

Here is a good overview of the query qsl   queries and their eqivalent in the high level rest client: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-query-builders.html

Comment: can you please provide an example of hos to use the terms query in this case?